# Jetty WebSocket Server

Tags: web-services, html, rest, webserver, websocket

Here's what:

I have a web service that will allow the web client to get and post data to.  That is already working.  What I want to happen is when an add,edit,delete happens in my web service UI, I want the changes to automatically be updated to the web client so that it has the accurate data.  So, people suggested I used a WebSocket in my server and client, so that the web service/client can send/receive messages anytime. What I want to do is, everytime an add,edit,delete happens the server will send a message like "please update your data", and when the client receives that, it will call an ajax method GET to fetch the data and load in the screen.

My web service is a Restful Web Service created from Netbeans wizard.  I've already downloaded the jetty jars.  Any ideas or good tutorials on how can I integrate that WebSocket thing in my web service?  I've seen tutorials on how to create WebSocket client, but no luck on the web server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project at github is a client side implementation for comet (including websockets of course ), But it also provides some sample server side implementations and one is with jetty websockets

https://github.com/flowersinthesand/jquery-socket/tree/master/samples/jetty-ws